# Selecting Top N rows

Tags: c#, sql

Everybody knows about this simple SQL query which used to select the top rows

```
    SELECT TOP 2 CostPrice

    FROM dbo.tblItemsQueue

    WHERE ItemCode='P0022'

    ORDER BY AddedDate ASC
```

It is clear when it has given a exact number with TOP (ex:- TOP 100). But according to my program I can't give an exact number with that. Instead of that, I have to enter a variable(eg :- N) with 'TOP' (ie :- SELECT TOP N CostPrice.....) and assign that variable by passing a value from C#

How can I do that in SQL Server? I used following method but it showed an error.

```
    @Qty int

    AS

    SELECT TOP @Qty CostPrice

    FROM dbo.tblItemsQueue

    WHERE ItemCode='P0022'

    ORDER BY AddedDate ASC
```

Comment: This is actually quite a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a variable to limit the row count you have to wrap the variable in parenthesis.

```
@Qty int

AS

SELECT TOP (@Qty) CostPrice

FROM dbo.tblItemsQueue

WHERE ItemCode='P0022'

ORDER BY AddedDate ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses around your variable

Then you get

```
SELECT TOP (@Qty) Costprice ...
```

However this will only work with sql 2005 +